# How does a substitution cipher work in C?

Tags: c, encryption

I've been researching the topic of encryption and I'm currently experimenting with using C. Does such a cipher work well in this programming language

Comment: Why wouldn't it work in C?

Comment: @Carcigenicate I didn't say it wouldn't but would it be easy to implement and code

Comment: How well do you know C?

Comment: @FelixPalmen fairly obviously 'not at all well' else the OP would already know "it's really easy" :(

Comment: If you are not very good on C, using Python that is a good selection to start cryptography programming. For learning python is Good and for actual critical using for example on embedded systems C is only solution.

Answer (score 2):

Yes: "C" is a good implementation language for encryption.
No: Basic substitution cipher are not good/secure. For data encryption use AES.

Essentially a substitution cipher replaces the message characters with other characters based on some schedule. Simple examples are the [Caesar cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher), [ROT13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13) and [One-time pad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad)—the first two are trivial, the last is completely secure if implemented properly.

To study there are many references on the web.

There is even a free PDF book: [*Handbook of Applied Cryptography*](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/index.html) by Alfred J. Menezes, Paul C. van Oorschot and Scott A. Vanstone, see free download. Chapter is a reasonable start for current ciphers.

Other books:

[*Cryptography Decrypted*](http://www.informit.com/store/cryptography-decrypted-9780201616477) by H. X. Mel and Doris M. Baker (good starter I really like)

[*Applied Cryptography*](https://www.schneier.com/books/applied_cryptography/) by Bruce Schneier

[*Cryptography Engineering*](https://www.schneier.com/books/cryptography_engineering/) by Niels Ferguson, Bruce Schneier, and Tadayoshi Kohno

There are also some good free courses in the web as [Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/courses?languages=en&query=cryptography) and [Udacity](https://www.udacity.com/course/applied-cryptography--cs387).